# Angular-cli fail to serve my project (cannot read property 'slice' of null)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My project was working fine until now (I have made some modifications of a node_modules file and ).

When I'm trying a "ng" command, i get this error :

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:34
            ? this._version.match(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:-(alpha|beta|rc)\.(.*))?$/).slice(1)
                                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at Version._parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:34:91)
    at Version.get [as major] (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:43:40)
    at Function.Version.isPreWebpack (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:142:24)
    at Function.Version.assertPostWebpackVersion (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:126:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:24:15
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:45:21
    at ondir (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:31)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:154:39
    at onex (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:94:22)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:25:18
```

My npm version is 3.10.8 and my node version 6.9.1. I have to tried to uninstall and reinstall angular-cli but it doesn't change anything... Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you print your "angular-cli" dependency line in your package.json ?

Comment: I somehow managed to change the project version inside angular-cli.json. Problem solved.

Comment: @user1386869, Please post your resolution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and changed the version referenced in the angular-cli.json file from a general beta version (i.e., `1.0.0-beta`) to a specific beta version such as `1.0.0-beta.26` so the regular expression (note the last `\.`) would correctly match and return array and not `null`.

```
// angular-cli.json
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "name": "name"
  },...
}
```